# Probability of pulling a good card out of a stack

Tags: probability

If I have a stack of 19 cards, of which I consider 6 of them to be good. I have the opportunity to pull a card out of the stack 3 times. What is the probability that I pull a good card? Once a card is pulled out of the stack it doesn't get placed back in.

Are the probabilities additive or multiplicative? It seems to me that there is approx 1 in 3 chance of pulling a good card (6 / 19), and then after that first pull if the card was good then there is now a 5/18 chance of a good card being pulled, but if the card was bad then there is a 6 / 18 chance of pulling a good card the second time and so on for the third pull. So adding that would give approx 0.3 + 0.3 + 0.3 = 0.9 chance of getting a good card out of 3. Is this the correct way to think about it?

Comment: The easier way to answer this question is to ask yourself the probability of pulling $3$ bad cards.  Take that number, subtract it from $1$, and you'll have the answer you want.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I have updated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hypergeometric distribution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2595744/hypergeometric-distribution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probabilities of events that can occur simultaneously (such as selecting one good and two bad cards) multiply, while probabilities of events that cannot occur at the same time (selecting exactly one bad card or selecting exactly two bad cards) add.

Let's follow Robert Shore's advice from the comments.  Since at least one good card is selected unless all three cards selected are bad, the probability of selecting at least one good card is found by subtracting the probability of selecting three bad cards from $1$.

We are told that there are six good cards, which means $19 - 6 = 13$ are bad.  The probability that we select three bad cards is
$$\Pr(\text{three bad cards are selected}) = \frac{\dbinom{13}{3}}{\dbinom{19}{3}}$$
Thus, the probability we pick at least one good card is
$$\Pr(\text{at least one good card is selected}) = 1 - \frac{\dbinom{13}{3}}{\dbinom{19}{3}}$$

For a direct count, we must either select one of the six good cards and two of the $13$ bad cards, two of the six good cards and one of the $13$ bad cards, or three of the six good cards while selecting three of the available $19$ cards.  Hence,
$$\Pr(\text{at least one good card is selected}) = \frac{\dbinom{6}{1}\dbinom{13}{2} + \dbinom{6}{2}\dbinom{13}{1} + \dbinom{6}{3}\dbinom{13}{0}}{\dbinom{19}{3}}$$

If you are not comfortable with using combinations, the probability of selecting three bad cards is
$$\Pr(\text{three bad cards are selected}) = \frac{13}{19} \cdot \frac{12}{18} \cdot \frac{11}{17}$$
Since there are initially $13$ bad cards in the deck, $12$ of the $18$ cards which remain after a bad card is selected with the first draw are bad cards, and $11$ of the $17$ cards which remain after two bad cards are selected are bad cards.  Reasoning as above, we obtain
$$\Pr(\text{at least one good card is selected}) = 1 - \frac{13}{19} \cdot \frac{12}{18} \cdot \frac{11}{17}$$

Trying to do a direct count without using combinations is more difficult since you would have to take the order of selection into account.  There are three possible positions for exactly one good card and three possible pairs of positions for exactly two good cards.